# How to create a variable number of columns for a DataGrid table?

Tags: c#, datagrid

**How can I create a DataGrid table with a variable number of columns?**

**Example:** Assuming we have a list of integer lists `List<List<int>>`. All inner lists have the same length `n`. Now I would like to create a row per integer list and for each integer an extra column.

For example: For the two integer lists `{1, 2, 3}` and `4, 5, 6` the DataGad would look like this:

```
1 | 2 | 3
--+---+---
4 | 5 | 6
```

Normally, I create an own class for my DataGrid row elements, like

```
class MyDataGridRecord {
  public int first { get; set; }
  public int second { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

But since I do not know how many columns I have, I can not write such a class with a fixed number of fields.

Comment: So you are saying that you have 3 columns in this example, but not in every example right?  That is how the columns vary?

Comment: Exactly, the length of the integer lists can vary. Another example could be: `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and `{5, 6, 7, 8}`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can do something like this:

```
var list = new List<List<int>>
        {
            new List<int>() {2, 3, 4, 5},
            new List<int>() {2, 3, 4, 5},
            new List<int>() {2, 3, 4, 5},
            new List<int>() {2, 3, 4, 5}
        };

var columnCount = list[0].Count;

for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
{
     dataGridView1.Columns.Add(i.ToString(),"Column " + i+1);
}
for (int k = 0; k < list.Count; k++)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows.AddCopy(0);
}


for (int k = 0; k < list.Count; k++)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < list[k].Count; i++)
      {
            dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[i].Value = list[k][i];
      }
}
```